# SQL Server 2008 lincensing question relating to web servers

Tags: web-server, sql-server-2008, licensing

We purchased SQL Server 2008 Standard licences last year under the server + device CAL licencing model.  Since our server has 2 physical CPUs and only 46 clients, this option was by far the cheapest.

Now we'd like to be able to query a small number of stored procedures from our Windows Server 2003 Web Edition server, which is in a seperate zone on our firewall.

I think SQL Server 2008 Web Edition could be an option to us, but is it possible to replicate/mirror stored procedures and tables to such a server and would we be breaking any rules by doing so?  Is this a form of multiplexing?

Also, would replication/mirroring work both ways, if we were to want to write back data from the web server?

Answer (score 1):

If the data from the main database ends up going to the publically accessible web then you need to change to per processor licences on your main server.  Microsoft make it very clear that they don't allow you to avoid it by having any intermediate thing in between.